# Is there a way to code something like this in C?

Tags: c

Input 1: 90009

Input 2: 8999

Input 3: 94738

(Output: 90009 94738 8999)
see the pattern
it sorts the value of 3 integer inputs in a such a way one input continues another by matching the starting digit and the ending digit of another integer

```
#include <stdio.h>



void swap( int *x , int * y)
{
double t = *x;
*x = *y;
*y = t;
}

int sort(int *x, int *y, int *z)
{

int getZ;
getZ = *z;
while(getZ>=10)
getZ=getZ/10;

if(*x % 10 == *y/ 1000)
swap(y,x);

if(*x%10 != *z/1000)
swap(z,y);

if(*y % 10 == getZ)
swap(z,y);
printf("Sorted Version is %d %d %d",*x,*y,*z);
}
```

For some reason im not getting the order that i want. Is there algorithm to write this code with?

Comment: This isn't a simple sort, I think. More like traversing a graph. It's going to get complicated.

Comment: I recommend that you use *strings* instead of integer for the input. Then it's really simple to find out the first and last digit of the numbers.

Comment: As for the sorting, for the example input why couldn't e.g. `94738 8999 90009` be valid as result? Please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the full and complete assignment into it, including any and all limitations and requirements.

Comment: Is input always only three numbers?

Comment: @bereal yeah its always three numbers

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just to check every permutation. This code can be more compactly written, but here's a very straightforward implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int first_digit(int n) {
    while (n > 10) n /= 10;
    return n;
}

int last_digit(int n) {
    return n % 10;
}

int sort(int *x, int *y, int *z) {
    int n[3] = {*x, *y, *z};
    int permutations[][3] = {
        {0, 1, 2},
        {0, 2, 1},
        {1, 0, 2},
        {1, 2, 0},
        {2, 0, 1},
        {2, 1, 0},
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(permutations) / sizeof(*permutations); i++) {
        int *idx = permutations[i];
        if (last_digit(n[idx[0]]) == first_digit(n[idx[1]]) && last_digit(n[idx[1]]) == first_digit(n[idx[2]])) {
            *x = n[idx[0]];
            *y = n[idx[1]];
            *z = n[idx[2]];
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int x=126, y=456, z=6001;
    if (sort(&x, &y, &z)) {
        printf("sorted version is %d %d %d\n", x, y, z);
    } else {
        printf("sort not possible for %d %d %d\n", x, y, z);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This gets really slow really fast when you add more numbers... But for up to some 10 to 13 numbers it's still feasible.